# How to configure server with nginx and apache?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have really old setup centOs server with apache and wordpress installed on it. I trying to install nginx on it and met the problem: 
- apache working on port 80
- nginx on port 81
this nginx config, i just put everything to one config file (without site_avialialbe)

```

````
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 81;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/api;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            root /usr/share/api;
            index index.html index.htm;
        }

    }
}

```
````

My node js application working with pm2 and using local address localhost:3001

And when i starting all, and call

`wget localhost:3000`

it just returning me 504 error.

if for example i trying to add some subdomain api.something.com it redirecting me automatically to main domain with wp website

Where i made mistake?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7)

Comment: @StefCoenen I was checked configuration problem is my server inside cannot call localhost

Comment: have you tested your node app itself already? `curl http://127.0.0.1:3001`

Answer (score 0):

For subdomain redirection issue, Is SSL enabled for the first site ( port 443 )?

504 is timeout error. When you do "wget localhost:3001", it hits your node server directly which is not returning any data, you need to check your application code

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, problem was with configuration in iptables, thank you everyone for help